# How to define the result of Solve as the variable

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions

Consider the operation

```
Solve[f[x,y,z] == 0, x]
```

I want to put the solutions for x obtained by this operation as the new variable. I tried to use ToString,

`xsol[y_,z_] = ToString[Solve[f[x,y,z] == 0, x]]`,

but this didn't give the desired result. Can you please help me?

Comment: `sol = Solve[f[x,y,z] == 0, x]` or `sol = Values@Solve[f[x,y,z] == 0, x]`?  I'm not really sure what you want, the rules or the values.

Comment: Note that `x`, must be a true variable, a symbol without a definition, for your `Solve` to work. If you give it a value, you cannot use it as a variable any more. That's one reason that replacement rules are more useful than what you seem to want.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : the operation Values@Solve[f[x,y,z] == 0, x] gives solution in brackets, e.g. (1.234455). How to remove them?

Comment: It gives the solution *set*; if you know there is always exactly one solution, then you can use `First@Values@Solve[..]` or `Part`, as in `Values[Solve[..]][[1]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using f[x,y,z] as a placeholder?  Or in your implementation is f[x,y,z] already defined?

Either way, a solution would be

```
xsol[y_, z_] = x /. Solve[f[x, y, z] == 0, x]
```

Out:

```
{InverseFunction[f, 1, 3][0, y, z]}
```

E.g. (f(x,y,z)=x^2-y+z)

Out:

```
{-√(y - z), √(y - z)}
```

If you'd like your answer to not have any brackets (as indicated in the comments), 
and you know your solution to be monovalued then use Part to extract the answer.

```
xsol[y_, z_] = Solve[f[x, y, z] == 0, x][[1]]
```

Out:

```
InverseFunction[f, 1, 3][0, y, z]
```

E.g. (f(x,y,z)=x+y+z)

Out:

```
-y - z
```

Warning: If your solution is multivalued, this will return an incomplete answer.

E.g. (f(x,y,z)=x^2-y+z)

Out:

```
-√(y - z)
```

ToString is not a good solution, because then that expression will no longer be able to be used (unless you use ToExpression).

Note: Mathematica actually suggests a similar thing to what you're asking when you evaluate a Solve:
[image: Mathematica suggestion]

Not quite (as it doesn't assign it to an actual variable), but close.